# what does "if first.col3" mean? Sas enterprise guide

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

what does "if first.col3" mean? (Sas enterprise guide)

```
Data table2;
set table1;
by col1 col2;
if first.col3;
run;
```

there is no statement after "if first.col3"

Answer (score 3):

`first.<variable-name>` is special variable that is set to a value of `1` when the variable name is listed in a `BY` statement, AND the value is from the first row of a new group comprised of the by variable and it's subordinate by variables.

For the use case of `first.<variable-name>` and variable-name is NOT in listed in a `BY` statement you will get a log line stating

```
NOTE: first.<variable-name> is uninitialized.
```

Uninitialized variables are assigned a missing value at the start of the DATA step.

An `if <expression>` statement WITHOUT a `then` is called a subsetting-if and program control continues beyond it only when the expression is true.

If your case then `if first.col3` has an expression that is never true because `col3` is not listed in the `BY` statement, so control never passed beyond the subsetting `if`.

A DATA Step without an explicitly coded `OUTPUT` statement will by default output a row when control reaches the end of the step.

In your case control never reaches the end of the step, so no OUTPUT ever occurs and the resultant data set `table2` will have zero rows.